# Javascript regex weird matching without global flag

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match a sequence of initials, the whole sequence, which the **second** regex in the following example does for me correctly. Why is it that I need the "global" flag? The first should also match ONLY the string in its entirety, right? (because of the `^` and the `$`)

```
abc = "A.B.C."
abc.match(/^([A-Z]\.)+$/) // result: ["A.B.C.", "C."]
abc.match(/^([A-Z]\.)+$/g) // result: ["A.B.C."]
```

thanks!

Comment: This probably has something to do with the capturing group.

Comment: It because of the `()` and the `+`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the parens do not include the `+`.  So when you do `abc.match(/^([A-Z]\.)+$/)`, the parens match only the first `[A-Z]\.`.

To get the match you want, you don't need the `g` flag.  Just use `match[0]` as your result.

```
var result = abc.match(/^([A-Z]\.)+$/)
if (result) {
    var fullMatch = result[0];
}
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/PXF6U/

See Bergi's answer for details on why the `g` flag changes the response like you observed.

Comment: ok, I can see how that works (`result[0]`), I still don't understand how `"C."` can be among the matching strings when it doesn't make up the whole string, which `^` and `$` should enforce. Seeing as I'm using `^` and `$` there should only be at most one match.

Comment: WAIT, I just figured out that the parens generate submatches, I just wanted to group the `[A-Z]` and the `\.` together, not also match just that, how do I do that?

Comment: "C." is a component match that corresponds to what your parents matched.  Every matching piece in parens comes back in the array.  The whole match is in `result[0]`.  The other component matches that were delineated with parens are in `result[1]`, `result[2]`, etc...

Comment: @pancake - use the code I've given you.  You need a submatch to make your `+` operator work properly.  Just ignore `result[1]` and use `result[0]`.

Comment: AHA, DUH, of course!!!! thank you very much!
It's exactly like \0, \1, \2 in VIM, I do not know how I could have misunderstood this.. thanks again!

Comment: Not that I'm ungrateful, but Bergi up there gave a clearer and more elaborate answer.

Comment: @pancake - you can decide who you want to reward, but they added the relevant code you need for a working solution to their answer 10 mins after it appeared in my answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11947/discussion-between-pancake-and-jfriend00)

Answer (score 2):

See the docs for the [`.match()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

> If the regular expression does not include the g flag, returns the same result as [`regexp.exec(string)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec).

This is your "unexpected result". See its [description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#Description): It will return an Array with capturing groups, the matched string, the index of the matching etc. The `"C."` you get as the second array item is the last capture of the `([A-Z]\.)` expression. Yet, it *did* match only the whole string once.

> If the regular expression includes the g flag, the method returns an Array containing all matches. If there were no matches, the method returns null.

The array of "all matches" will have only one item, since you match `^...$`.

So, regardless which regexp you will use, the code should be:

```
var result = abc.match(regex);
if (result) // != null
    return result[0];
else
    // no match found
```

Answer (score 2):

If you apply a quantifier (in this case `+`) to a capturing subpattern (`([A-Z]\.)`) then only the last instance of that repeated subpattern is captured (because it is index 1 of the result array, and it is overwritten every time a new ones is found).

If you want to get the individual matches, try:

```
abc.match(/[A-Z]\./g);
```

This will give you:

```
["A.","B.","C."]
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, this also enhances my knowledge of js regex behavior.